# Possible to use Visual Studio 2010 web performance test on page with jquery dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

Has anyone successfully tested a Web Forms application containing jQuery dialogs using the Web Performance Test tools in Visual Studio 2010?  I have recorded several now but they don't ever run without errors.  It seems very confused by the jQuery dialogs.  Our dialogs are iframes that are loaded using the dialog widget and have querystring parameters passed in.  If a regular web perf test doesn't work how do you test these apps?  Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the web performance test on web forms, but what are you trying to get?  Actual numbers/values from performance monitoring?  Or suggestions on how to speed up your applicaton.  If the latter, you can install YSlow (along with firebug) as a firefox extension, and see what it says about your site and how to streamline it.